# Continually running JavaScript code after an interval of time

Tags: javascript, html, time, timer, meta

I would like to know if it is possible to load a script tag after an interval of time has elapsed. I need a library but is not running all the time. Here is my script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cssrefresh.js" ></script>
```

I would like to run my function every hour. How can I accomplish this?

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you just have a `setTimer` in the script, that will run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Loading a new script every hour would make more requests to the server, add data, reduce time and is generally a bad practice. It is better to just run one function with `setInterval`.

It's important to note that the time argument in `setInterval` counts the number of milliseconds. 1 hour is 3600000 milliseconds, so we pass that in as the parameter.

Inside a script tag, it would look like this

```html
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        alert('Runs every hour');
    }, 3600000);
</script>
```

This means the above function will be called every hour. If you're willing to wait that long, by all means test it out.

Edit: It's also possible to refresh the page every hour. You do this by creating a `meta` tag with attribute `http-equiv`, set it's value to `refresh`. Then you create a `content` attribute setting it's value to 3600.

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
</head>
```

It's better to use my first solution though.

Answer (score 0):

A script should be loaded and then should just stay there. If you want script to run hourly, then you should implement that in the *script*, not the HTML.

So, if you want to run some code hourly, try this:

```
// Time in hours
time = 1;
function codeToRunEveryXTime() {
    // Code to run
}
//Setting a timer to run the above function, every hour, converting time into milliseconds
setInterval(codeToRunEveryXTime,time*3600000);
```

If you're confused, just think of your script as this:

```
// Code to run
```

So put my code into your script, and put whatever you had in place for `// Code to run`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Oh my gosh how did I not see that :D @RichardHamilton thanks for helping me out here :).